# Statically allocate object without need to know its size

Tags: c++, linker, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to optimize compilation times of a considerably big embedded control software.
Today at the top level we have something in the spirit of

```cpp
// software.h
#include "component_a.h"
// ...
#include "component_n.h"

class Software
{
     // 
     Component_A m_component_a;
     //..
     Component_N m_component_n;
};

// software.cpp
Software g_software_singleton {};

// somewhere else
Legacy_Logging_System g_logging_system(g_software_singleton.get_pointer_to_something()); // many of these
```

This is quite monolithic and results in a compilation bottleneck, because any change to a header file directly or indirectly included will retrigger a rebuild of a huge compilation unit with a big portion of our code-base.

Unfortunately we have several **conflicting requirements** that make optimizing this harder:

1. an important legacy system requires this to be allocated statically, because addresses are taken pre-main and cannot be changed later on. If that was not the case, we could use e.g. a PIMPL pattern.
2. Efficient way to allocate the `Component`s. I could turn this into N individual singletons for the embedded software, but would like to be able to re-use the allocation code, because also tests and simulations on PC have to allocate all of them (There I would like to avoid a global singleton and be able to e.g. instantiate `Software` more than once).
3. Guaranteed construction order. The `Components` partially depend on each other, so creating them independently in different compilation units, risks ending up in unreproducible issues depending on the link order.

The main limitation of C++ I see here, is that the *size* of structures must be known at compile time and - unlike for variable and function *addresses* - cannot be deferred to the linker.

A **possible solution** I came up with so far is using a statically allocated memory pool and still has the drawbacks of

1. has to be speculatively sized "big enough"
2. might require link time optimization for efficient look-ups

```cpp
template<std::size_t bytes> class Memory_Pool { /* ... */ };

Memory_Pool g_pool {};

class Software
{
    // minimum size needed here - **UGLY** 
    char m_memory_pool[1234];

    Component_A* m_component_a;
    Component_B* m_component_b;

    void make_component_a();
    // ...
    void make_component_n();

    // Turning size from a compile time thing into a run-time or link-time thing
    std::size_t get_offset_a() { return 0; }
    // ...
    std::size_t get_offset_n();

public:
    Software() :
        m_component_a(make_component_a()),
        // ..
        m_component_n(make_component_n())
    {
         assert(/* big enough pool*/);
    }
};

// multiple compilation units for the same class - **UGLY**
// software_component_a.cpp
#include "component_a.h" // only depending on A
void Software::make_component_a() 
{ 
    Component_A* result = m_memory_pool[get_offset_a()];
    
    // in place new - **UGLY**
    new (result) Component_A ( /* ... */ );

    return result;
}

std::size_t Software::get_offset_b() 
{ 
    return get_offset_a() + sizeof(A); 
}

// software_component_n.cpp
#include "component_n.h" // only depending on N
void Software::make_component_N(Memory_Pool& memory_pool) { /* .. */ }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `extern Software g_software_singleton;`? You'll need to define and initialize the object in another translation unit(ie. CPP source file) and add the translation unit in your project property file.

Comment: @Red.Wave nothing wrong with that. I try to avoid singletons mostly because they are kind of "viral", but with my requirements I'll need at least one, but ideally not more. I would like to keep this number low, but speed up compilation.

Comment: That's why this works. You're putting the object in another TU and compile it only once. On future builds, it is just linked, not compiled; thus reduces build time.

Comment: Except if a) any of the files included by the top level header changes (which is very frequently the case given their number) or b) many test cases need to access some part of it, and their TU will also be rebuilt.

Comment: do you suggest that this overhead is avoidable? I seriously don't think so. Prove me wrong, if that's what you believe. I just guess the OP is not used to implementing this well-known pattern. It used to be called *modular programming*; but since the `module` feature -as part of the standard- is about to be adopted by all tool-chain makers, I don't like to use ambiguous terminology.